# Cannot use mkdir in script : Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating several scripts to launch some programs, then a regourped them in one toplevel.sh script , first script is a toplevel_config.sh where i export all the path i need :

```
    export TARGET_FOLDER="home2/marwa/Desktop/folder/test_all/prot_x"
    export TARGET_FILE="prot_x"
```

everything is working except in one scrpit when i have to creat a directory , i have this error :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/top10_prot_x’: Permission denied
```

The script responsible is :

```
results_path=${TRAGET_FOLDER}/sam_results/vmd_results/namd_results/*.out
top10_path=${TRAGET_FOLDER}/top10_${TARGET_FILE}

if [ ! -d "$top10_path" ]; then
   mkdir "$top10_path"
fi
```

Comment: `TRAGET_FOLDER != TARGET_FOLDER`

Comment: If you do this sort of thing frequently, consider `set -u` to error on unset variables.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to mkdir in another path than expected.

Your variable path are:

```
results_path=${TRAGET_FOLDER}/sam_results/vmd_results/namd_results/*.out
top10_path=${TRAGET_FOLDER}/top10_${TARGET_FILE}
```

But you define

```
export TARGET_FOLDER="home2/marwa/Desktop/folder/test_all/prot_x"
export TARGET_FILE="prot_x"
```

So ${TRAGET_FOLDER} = null and no exist.

Besides, ‘/top10_prot_x’ already explain that.

Comment: thank you for answer, i change the path and t works but honestly i still dont understand why it is not the same TARGET_FOLRER.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions and the user that execute your script, try ls -l command to check if you are allowed to create directories/files.